# Silverlight - Binding to Enumeration

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have a combobox in a C# Silverlight application. My view model has a property called `DayOfWeek`. This property needs to match the [standard .NET `DayOfWeek` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx).

Is there a way I can populate my combobox with the values of this enumeration? Also, is there a way for me wire it up with my view-model so that the selected value propagates back-and-forth to/from my viewmodel? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek> _weekDays;

// In the constructor:
_weekDays = new ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek>();
_weekDays.AddRange(new DayOfWeek[] {
    DayOfWeek.Sunday,
    DayOfWeek.Monday,
    DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
    DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
    DayOfWeek.Thursday,
    DayOfWeek.Friday,
    DayOfWeek.Saturday
});

// Properties of your VM:
public ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek> WeekDays
{
    get
    {
        return _weekDays;
    }
}

public DayOfWeek SelectedDay
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding WeekDays}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDay, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When you use the combobox, the value of `SelectedDay` will change.  If you want to change the value from code, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire `PropertyChanged` from the setter of `SelectedDay`.